# Error while trying to execute pl/sql that loops through a cursor containing only ROWID's

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, rowid

I'm trying to update all the columns in a given table.
This table has ~200,000,000 records in it.

Trying to run a simple update statement doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE ROW_ID_TBL IS TABLE OF ROWID;
    CURSOR c_rowIdCursor RETURN ROWID IS
        SELECT ROWID FROM SOME_TABLE;

    v_RowIDs ROW_ID_TBL;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_rowIdCursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_rowIdCursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_RowIDs LIMIT 50000;
        EXIT WHEN v_RowIDs.COUNT = 0;

        FORALL i IN v_RowIDs.FIRST..v_RowIDs.LAST
            UPDATE SOME_TABLE
               SET SOME_KEY = MOD(NVL(REGEXP_REPLACE(ALPHA_NUMERIC_VAL, '[^0-9]+', ''), 0), 300)+1
             WHERE ROWID = v_RowIDs(i);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I get the following when I try to run it:

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 33:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
```

Comment: Is `SOME_KEY` NULL for all rows before they are updated? If so, you could do this with a simple `UPDATE...WHERE some_key IS NULL AND ROWNUM <= 50000`, put this in a loop, and exit the loop when SQL%ROWCOUNT is zero.

Comment: It is far too slow that way. I had already tried that. It took 4 times as long (3.7 hrs).

Comment: My comment was intended to help you overcome the "out of memory" issue - which means sacrificing performance. Although, it may be feasible to overcome the performance issue with a suitable functional index on `some_key` - which may or may not be appropriate to your situation.

Comment: We extended the undo Tablespace to 60GB, but INSERT INTO still won't work. However removing RETURN ROWID worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CURSOR` definition is incorrect.  You want something like

```
CURSOR c_rowIdCursor
    IS SELECT ROWID 
         FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Of course, I'm not sure why a simply update wouldn't work.  It would be more efficient, it would use fewer resources, and it would require less code.

Comment: It broke with a shared pool memory `could not extend segment by X` error.

Comment: @scrappythenell - What was the exact error?  Generally, you'd get the same error if you tried to break the update into pieces-- it sounds like one of your tablespaces is out of space.

Comment: I think it is the undo tablespace that is too small. Breaking it up works.